# subscribemapping not called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

i have to use returned value from a web socket.
i try to use @SubscribeMapping Annotated method to handle and use this block to handle my biz.
sample code is:

```
 @MessageMapping({"/hello"})
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception { 
        return new Greeting("Thread Id:"+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
    }

@SubscribeMapping("/topic/greetings")
public void test(Greeting greeting){
    System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE CALLED");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

topic prefix is automatically added. omit "/topic"

```
@SubscribeMapping("/greetings")
public void test(Greeting greeting){
    System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE CALLED");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can change `@SubscribeMapping` to `@MessageMapping`, hope it helps!